# Can we create IKM using Oracle ODI SDK Public API, in ODI 11G?

Tags: java, oracle, oracle11g, oracle-data-integrator

how to load data from a SQL Query into a target database using Custom Knowledge Module (KM) of Oracle Data Integrator (ODI 11g).
Using Custom KM in ODI 11g the code generation capabilities of ODI were extended in order to build larger and very complex query to simple interface designs without the necessity of staging area via temporary interface (Yellow Interface).

I would like to build NEW IKM using ODI SDK(Java) in ODI 11g. I did not find any reference anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

This kind of KM already exists. David Allan developed it and explains how it works in [this blog post](https://blogs.oracle.com/warehousebuilder/odi-11g-ndash-simple,-flexible,-powerful). The download link for the IKM is dead but you can find it on [this page](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/indexes/samplecode/dataintegration-sample-522116.html) under the name ***IKM SQL as a Source***.

This KM is for 11g only. For 12c, a Custom Template field is available in the physical tab of a mapping to override the extract query for each source. This is describe by Bhabani Ranjan on [his blog](http://dwteam.in/query-as-source-in-12c/).

Comment: Yeah, I have got that, It is really helpful Thanks, Similar kind of thing I created using ODI Java SDK. I am stuck on one point https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48096919/how-to-check-derived-table-statement-in-ikm-using-odi-sdk-in-odi-11g