# How to check "Derived table statement" in ikm using ODI SDK in ODI 11g?

Tags: java, oracle, groovy, oracle-data-integrator

I am trying to generate Ikm with Derived table statement in source command.
I can able to set source command but not able to check the check box "Derived table statement" as shown in picture below.

The code I was trying is

```
SqlGroupType pSqlGroupType = Expression.SqlGroupType.CONSTANT;//valueOf("SQLQUERY");
    String exp="(<%=odiRef.getUserExit(“SQLQUERY”)%>)";
    Expression pExpression= new Expression(exp, pCrossRefs, pSqlGroupType);
    pSourceCommand.setExpression(pExpression);;

    Collection<ProcedureOption> pGenerationConditions=null;

    ob.addLine("SQLQUERY", pTargetCommand, pSourceCommand, pGenerationConditions);
    OdiIKMLine pLine =null ;
    ob.setDerivedSelectStatementLine(pLine);
```

[image]

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: Thanks, Sure I will refer recommended keyword.